# Как уменьшить расход памяти? php, cURL, array

Tags: массивы, память, php, оптимизация, curl

Собираю два массива А и Б по ~миллиону целых чисел из веб сервиса, чтобы затем сосчитать их пересечение. Сервис отдаёт за один запрос 1000 чисел, поэтому в цикле около 1000 раз для каждого приходится делать запрос через cURL. Коннекшн один, используется снова и снова: подставляются новые значения в `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`, и снова `curl_exec()`.

Полученный json разбирается, и очередной массив с 1000 целых чисел merge'ится в А или Б.

Пока это всё работает в виде пруф-оф-концепт на shared хостинге руЦентра, где памяти выделено всего ничего. С партиями меньше миллиона скрипт справляется. Больше - вылетает с фатальной ошибкой об исчерпанной памяти. Иногда на этапе получения второго миллиона из сервиса, иногда уже после, на этапе сравнения.

Вместо ф-ий `array_merge()` и `array_intersect()` уже использую свои, менее ресурсоёмкие: мне не нужно сортировать и получать само пересечение, достаточно сосчитать кол-во общих.

Не может только массив целых с 2 млн. значений занимать десятки мегов памяти же! Как понять, раздувается ли это cURL при каждом новом обращении? Или, может, массивы хранят значения не как целые по 4 байта, а как строки например?

Сориентируйте, пожалуйста, с оптимизацией по памяти - куда копать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Имхо при ужатой памяти вам проще на БД переложить этот процесс. Работать будет дольше, но памяти есть меньше. Может быть, можно будет даже часть алгоритмов на базу переложить.

Далее, в php с памятью такая анархия, что лучше даже не интересоваться. Достаточно сказать, что размер массива всегда степень двойки (в большую сторону), состоит он из указателей(4-8 байт) на int, а int - это структура(имя, тип, размер etc).

И далее, если можно обрабатывать все в процессе - do it. Т.е. получили тысячу, обработали, выкинули, погнали дальше. Если нет - БД. Теоретически можно попробовать с временными файлами поколдовать, но вряд ли этот способ сильно выиграет у БД по удобству/скорости.

Comment: Разумно, спасибо. Скорость не принципиальна, поэтому переложить нагрузку на БД — отличный совет.

Comment: поддерживаю использование БД

Comment: Извините, а в случае БД расходы памяти идут за чужой счёт? Тогда -- однозначно да. Иначе -- лучше что-то более специально написанное (если есть возможность это использовать)

Comment: @alexlz в <strike>клиническом</strike> случае с руЦентром память и нагрузка БД не учитываются в квотах хостинга. Так что, да, флаг и барабаны!

Comment: @alexlz, БД - это все-таки хард. Вряд ли надо будет всю базу загружать в оперативку, а при средних лимитах 64-129МБ оперативки vs 5-15ГБ харда второй явно выигрывает)

Comment: @Sh4dow перечитал свой комментарий. Не понял. И где там написано про оперативку? И даже в случае оперативки, потребности сильно зависят от условий задачи. Напр: сколько минимально памяти надо для представления множества чисел 1..10^6? (ответ: 10^6/8 байт -- это около 125Кб)

Comment: @alexlz, я про "за чужой счет". И да, минимально - это не про PHP ))

    <?php
    $a = array();
    $mem = memory_get_peak_usage();
    for ($i = 0; $i < 1000000; $i++)
      $a [] = $i;
    $memnow = memory_get_peak_usage() - $mem;
    echo round($memnow / 1024 / 1024, 4).' MB';
    ?>
    out: 80.2918 MB

А учить язык ради одной задачи я бы тоже не стал)

Comment: Если есть возможность выполнять системные команды, то вполне неплох вариант - построчно сливаются значения в два файла, следом на них натравливается команда join, результат которой и собирается в массив, если требуется. Но в этом случае php толком и не используется - нагрузка падает на непосредственно систему.